# Input pattern attribute to change color of an input box

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am working on a program that creates a spreadsheet type format with a bunch of input boxes arranged in a table. I currently have everything color coded so that when data is uploaded into the table, some regular expressions help change the colors. But only on upload.

However I would also like to be able to dynamically change the colors as I input data by hand (as opposed to just uploading a file and calling the colors done.)

I was told to look into using the `input` tag's `pattern` attribute that allowed for matching regular expressions. This seems very applicable, yet I don't know how I'd write a JavaScript function that made use of this. I have my regular expressions and I know what colors I want to use, but I don't know how I'd run a function in the pattern.

My upload colors the boxes by running a function on each piece of data, and if it's a certain color, it pushes it into that certain color of array. Another function, upon creation of the table, checks to see what pieces of data are in what array. It then returns "red," "blue," or "green." All of these which I use in my `class` attribute for the `input` tag.

So let's say I have

```
var blue_regex = (/([A-Z0-9]+\*\d+:\d+:\d+)(.+)/);
var red_regex = /(\*\d\d$)/;
```

And

```
makeColors = function(data) {
    if (red.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
        return "red";
    }
    else if (blue.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
        return "blue";
    }
    else {
        return "green"; //returns green by default
    };
};
```

where `makeColors` is called in the class of the `input` tag.

I don't want to deal with pushing and popping items out of these red and blue arrays I mention, but simply changing the colors with the `pattern` attribute, keeping in mind that I am also using the `class` method to hold these colors.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: A pattern is a RegEx object, not an <input> method. You should just read up on javascript regular expressions. It would take half an hour to understand the basics. One advanced gotcha: You might need to worry about copying and pasting of strings into an input field. If someone pastes 100 chars into the field, are you going to run the regex test 100 times in a row? Seems like you might have to. But you'll also have to erase the input of all the chars after the bad one.

Comment: I understand regular expressions. I am looking for some way to create a function that would run every time a change is detected in the input box. whether it be character by character, or when the user clicks out of the box, it doesn't matter to me. The pattern attribute in an input tag checks inputted content to match a given regex, so I was hoping I could maybe make that work for me with some sort of function. Please see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) as it refers to the pattern attribute I am talking about.

Comment: I think you want to bind to the input 'change' event. If you use jquery it would be something like `$(input).change(function({...}));` then inside you can check if the value matches the pattern attribute and add a class or add it to your color arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is a working example, I don't know what your data looks like so I just made up some [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) patterns to match on. It feels a little hacky and you'd probably want to use [JQuery to change the classes](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) instead of using the classname, but this works and is simple so here you go...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <style>
            .red {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .blue {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .green {
                background-color: green
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            function applyColour(event){

                // the input value
                var text = event.target.value;

                //match on any 3 letters in a row that are upper or lower case and from 'a to o'
                var isRed = new RegExp(/[A-Oa-o]{3}/g);

                //match on any 3 letters in a row that are upper or lower case and from 'p to z'
                var isBlue = new RegExp(/[P-Zp-z]{3}/g);

                // use the test() method from regexp to return true/false on the match
                if (isRed.test(text)){
                    event.target.className = "red";
                } else if (isBlue.test(text)){
                    event.target.className = "blue";
                } else if (text.length > 0){
                    event.target.className = "green";
                } else {
                    event.target.className = "";
                }
            }


        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input onkeyup="applyColour(event)" />
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see it works with the `onkeyup` [event dispatched from the input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) as a person types, you could change this to use others such as `onchange` for example, there are subtle differences, this seemed to be the most dynamic for the short example.

I didn't use the inputs `pattern` attribute as that seems more useful when checking the input is valid against a regular expression and is probably more useful for final validation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the pattern from the pattern attribute with jQuery and then use the .match function to run your color function when the pattern actually matches?